# is time in mapdist function real-time travel time or static?

Tags: r, ggmap

I am interested in driving distance and time using the [`mapdist`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/ggmap/docs/mapdist) function in `ggmap`.

Is this travel time timely updated (real-time traffic information) or constant (travel time is always the same whenever we use "mapdist" for each OD? Thanks!

```
mapdist(from='18.958011, 72.819789', to='18.958558, 72.831462', mode="driving", output="simple")
```

I got the information like time:

```
from                   to    m    km     miles seconds  minutes      hours
1 18.958011, 72.819789 18.958558, 72.831462 1304 1.304 0.8103056     241 4.016667 0.06694444
```

Comment: Could you explain little more what you mean as timely "updated or constant?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function uses standard [google API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/?csw=1). There you can find that you would have to specify optional parameter `departure_time` to your request, to take traffic under consideration.

And if you look into [`mapdist` source code](https://github.com/dkahle/ggmap/blob/master/R/mapdist.R#L63) you can see that `departure_time` is not part of your request (neither as parameter, or default option).